# How to know if nginx rtmp streaming is stopped or finished?

Tags: nginx, rtmp, nginx-rtmp

We are trying to make a live streaming and we implemented nginx rtmp module and added `on_publish` callback to check if the stream key is valid or not.

Now we need one thing

1. We need to call api like `on_publish` when the user stops streaming for example clicks `stop streaming` in OBS.

I tried with `on_done` but it is called every few seconds automatically not when stream is closed.

How to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough; you have to use `on_publish_done`

Documentation [here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#notify)

Comment: tried using this as well. This also get called every few seconds.

Comment: Can you post your code? Nginx.conf file and API file.

Comment: Hello @JuanTrejos Difference between on_publish and on_play? I see both mentioned in the nginx rtmp module docs.